# Is There a Way to Make a NULL Value Act as an Optional Condition in MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, optional-parameters

I'm trying to write a JDBC query with 20 optional search parameters. I would like to know how to make a set of parameters that do not have a value (null) not to be included in the SQL without having too many if/else statements to construct the SQL string manually.

I cannot use `... AND (column = :value OR column IS NULL)` when the value is actually null as the query search result would not be correct.

Comment: try this `(:value IS NULL OR column = :value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the column data type and its parameter is nullable OR Not.

**General Search Condition AND/OR:**

```
WHERE
   (:col1 = col1_special_value OR col1 = :col1)
   AND
   (:col2 IS NULL OR col2 = :col2)
   AND
   // ...
```

**Sample User Search:**

```
WHERE
   (:name IS NULL OR name = :name) // :name is String - Nullable
   AND
   (:age = 0 OR age = :age)    // :age is int - Not nullable
   AND
   // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax for each search parameter

```
WHERE 
(
    (tableName.colName = val) 
    OR 
    (tableName.colName IS NULL AND val IS NULL)
)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow indent by 4 spaces to form code blocks (or use the handy shortcut/button in the editor), don't use triple backticks.